# Windows breaks bootloader in dual boot with Pop OS

Tags: linux, systemd, boot, dual-boot, pop-os

I have an installation of Windows 10 and Pop on separate partitions of the same drive and I want to dual boot them with systemd-boot, which is the default for Pop OS.

I followed [this guide](https://github.com/spxak1/weywot/blob/main/Pop_OS_Dual_Boot.md) (the TL;DR version is good enough) because I didn't have Windows in the boot menu selection. The guide just tells you to copy the EFI files from the Windows EFI partition into the Pop OS EFI partition so systemd-boot can recognize Windows. This works fine and both Windows and Pop appear in the boot menu.

When I boot Pop there is no issue. However, when I boot Windows everything works fine for the first time, but then after a reboot cycle all Pop OS partitions disappear from the boot menu and instead the computer boots into the GRUB terminal (?? GRUB wasn't even being used before). The Pop partition is no longer recognized as bootable and I can't boot into Pop.

This problem is reproducible. It happens every time I do the above steps. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, and I hope someone answers this question. I share my laptop, and one day Grub was missing, and none of the pop os partitions showed up in the bios boot menu. I created a live usb media to use the grub customizer, and under my pop os root file, the windows boot loader was missing, but the pop os boots were there. I checked the disk partitions, and all of pop os partitions were still available.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/415604)

Answer (score 0):

There are two windows bootoader sets from the encrypted key and one is a spare of another if the connection choices does not match with the default factory pattern to prevent bios total damage from user error. It's a security protection system from the ios vendor. You have to reintegrate the device from the remote support assistant.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please consider revising your post - as it is currently written, it is difficult to understand.